# Using query string parameter in Kentico marketing automation process

Tags: automation, kentico

I am trying to set up a marketing automation process that is kicked off when a user visits a particular web page on my site. The URL to that web page is going to be included in an email blast to a set of Kentico contacts.

I was hoping to be able to add a query string parameter to the end of the URL so that I can capture the e-mail address of the contact and store it in the Contact Email field,

i.e. http://example.com/mypage?email=xx@xxx.com.

My first attempt at this was setting up a marketing automation workflow that is triggered when the user visits the page, then using a 'Set Contact Property' step to set the contact's email address to the query string value, but I can't seem to be able to get the value of the query string parameter. I've tried {? email?}, {% QueryString.email%}, etc. with no luck.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.  Try this:

```
{% QueryString["nameOfQueryString"] %}
```

So if my URL were http://www.exmaple.com/mypage?email=testEmail@example.com, and I wanted to resolve the query string called "email" I would write:

```
{% QueryString["email"] %}
```

And it would resolve "testEmail@example.com".

**Side Note:** I would not recommend using your users' emails as the query string.  I would use a GUID to build the URL and associate the user's email with a GUID in a SQL table.

So, if the email address "testEmail@exaple.com" was associated to the guid 25892e17-80f6-415f-9c65-7395632f0223, you would build a URL like this:

http://www.exmaple.com/mypage?id=25892e17-80f6-415f-9c65-7395632f0223

Then when the user visits this page, you can tell who they are by comparing the GUID to their email.